# android app force closes

Tags: android, android-xml

i have this android code .I have my layout for button defined in the xml file .i want to set the text for button here by getting it by id .but the app force closes.whats wrong ?

```
  package com.action ;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class ActionActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle i){
         super.onCreate(i);
         Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
         button.setText("Hey!!");
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         }
}
```

Thnx...

Comment: Post the output from logcat aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` before using `findViewById()`.

If you don't do that, `findViewById()` will return `null` (since no view with that ID is in the current layout) and you will get a `NullPointerException` when trying to set the text on the `TextView`.

The correct version of `onCreate()` should look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle i) {
    super.onCreate(i);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    button.setText("Hey!!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put setContentView(R.layout.main) before creating the instance of Button.
Like This:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    button.setText("Hey!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you must put setContentView(R.Layout.main) before setting findViewById(R.id.but).Because it generates nullpointer Exception.